# iOS - Look for and manipulate text field by tag?

Tags: ios, text, foreach, tags

I have 'inc' and 'dec' buttons for a series of fields in an iOS app that I am using to manipulate matching text fields.  I've looked in all my references and can't quite get how to iterate through the text views by tag, and be able to manipulate them from there.  I found how to at least list them out, but that doesn't quite finish the job.

I apologize for what may be an easy question, but I haven't found how to do it yet - is it possible, or do I have to write separate code for each button?

Comment: Can I just confirm what you are asking: are you trying to use 1 update method for all of the buttons, and then change the correct text field, and you are unable to differentiate between the buttons?

Comment: I can differentiate between the buttons, but need to determine the matching text field for each set.  The IBOutletCollection below appears to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use tags for this.

Create a reference to each object in the controller, assign them to an [IBOutletCollection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html) which you can then use to enumerate the objects:

[image]